# What is needed to create react app offline?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am working offline without any internet connectivity. I have Node.js installed on my system. When I try to run the `npm create-react-app` command it gives me an error. Is there any way for me to run npm commands and get react application running offline? If I create react app on another computer (with an internet connection) and took that in my PC via pen drive, will it work?  Below is the error code I get:

```
npm ERR! errcode ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed,
reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, I saw that you are using the command `npm create-react-app`. I think, it should be `npx create-react-app`.

*NPM by itself does not simply run any package. it doesn't run any package in a matter of fact.* 
*npx will check whether  exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute it*

And if you run the `create react app` function on another computer (with internet connection) and take that to your PC via pen drive, it will work.